# Solr: Localities & solr.ICUCollationField usage?

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm learning Solr and have become confused trying to figure out ICUCollation, what it does, what it is for and how to use it. From [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Language+Analysis#LanguageAnalysis-UnicodeCollation). I haven't found any good explanation of this online. The doc appear to be saying that I need to use this ICUCollation and implies that it does magical things for me, but does not seem to explain exactly why or exactly what, and how it integrates with anything else.

Say I have a text field in French and I want stopwords removed, accents, punctuation and case ignored and stemming... how does ICUCollation come into this? Do I set `solr.ICUCollationField` and `locale='fr'` and it will do everything else automatically? Or do I set `solr.ICUCollationField` and then tokenizer and filters on this in addition? Or do I not use `solr.ICUCollationField` at all because that's for something completely different? And if so, then what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collation is [the organisation of written information into an order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation) - ICUCollactionField ([the API documentation also provides a good description](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_9_0/solr-analysis-extras/org/apache/solr/schema/ICUCollationField.html)) is meant to enable you to provide locale aware sorting, as the sort order is defined by cultural norms and specific language properties. This is useful to allow different sorting based on those rules, such as the difference between Norwegian and Swedish, where a Swede would order Å before Æ/Ä and Ø/Ö, while a Norwegian would order it Æ/Ä, Ø/Ö and then Å.

Since you usually don't want to sort by a tokenized field (exception: KeywordTokenizer) or a multivalued field, these fields are usually not processed any more than allowing for the sorting / collation to be performed.

There is a case to be made for collation filters for searching as well, as search in practice is just comparison. This means that if you're aiming to search for two words that would be identical when compared in the locale provided, it would be a hit. The tokens indexed will not make any sense when inspected, but as long as the values are reduced to the same token both when indexing and searching, it would work. There's [an example of this on the wiki under UnicodeCollation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UnicodeCollation).

Collation does not affect stopwords ([StopFilterFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.StopFilterFactory)), accents ([ICUFoldingFilterFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ICUFoldingFilterFactory)), punctuation, case (depending on locale - if the locale for sorting is case aware, then it does not) ([LowercaseFilterFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory) or [ICUNormalizer2FilterFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ICUNormalizer2FilterFactory)) or stemming ([SnowballPorterFilterFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageAnalysis#Notes_about_solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory)). Have a look at the suggested filters for that. Most filters or tokenizers in Solr does very specific tasks, and try to avoid doing "everything and the kitchen sink" in one single filter.

Comment: OK, so all this does is decide on the sorting order? Considering that I will be removing accents from characters and using only Latin alphabet, does that mean that I do not need to use ICUCollactionField at all and would be better off just with a standard string field?

Comment: As long as you're happy with the way the standard latin1 char values sort, you can just use StrField or a TextField with KeywordTokenizer (if you need to lowercase it on the Solr side or something similiar).

Comment: Sorry to ask something else, but what does it matter what order the strings sort?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking .. if you want your hits sorted by a string, the sort order matter. If you don't, then it doesn't matter. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You normally have two or more fields for one text input if you want to do different things like:

- search: text analysis
- sort: language sensitive / case insensitive sorting
- facet: string

For search use something like:

```
<fieldType name="textFR" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.ICUTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ICUFoldingFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ElisionFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordRepeatFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.FrenchLightStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

For sorting use:

```
<fieldType name="textSortFR" class="solr.ICUCollationField"
           locale="fr"
           strength="primary" />
```

or simply:

```
<fieldType name="textSort" class="solr.ICUCollationField"
           locale=""
           strength="primary" />
```

(If you have to support many languages. Should work fine enough in most cases.)

Do make use of the Analysis UI in the SOLR Admin: open the analysis view for your index, select the field type (e.g. your sort field), add a representative input value in the left text area and a test value in the right field (in case of sorting, this right side value is not as interesting as the sort field is not used for matching).

The output will show you whether:

- accents are removed
- elisions are removed
- lower casing is applied

etc.

For example, if you see that elisions (l'atelier) are not remove (atelier) but you would like to discard it for sorting you would have to add the elision filter (see example for search field type above).

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Language+Analysis